# How to integrate service now with nagios core?

Tags: centos7, nagios

i have installed the nagios core. and i want integrate the service now with nagios core open source.
I didnt find any documents regarding. could you help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Either just send an email to service now who will process it, or write a command that calls the service now api.
E.g. an event handler
https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/eventhandlers.html

An email should be enough I would think....